# Entity Framework, Unity, and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container

I have a multi tier application using Entity Framework, MVC and Unity.
The basic setup is like this:

EF Data Access Layer

```
public class MyDataProvider : DbContext, IMyDataProvider 
{


    public MyDataProvider(SqlConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection,contextOwnsConnection)
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 60;

        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

    }

    public new IDbSet<TModel> Set<TModel>() where TModel : class
    {
        return base.Set<TModel>();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EmployeeMapping());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

public abstract class ServiceBase<TModel> : IDisposable, IService<TModel> where TModel : class, IModel
{
    [Dependency]
    public IMyDataProvider MyDataProvider { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

All services inherit from this class

I then inject specific services into the Business Logic Layer like so:

```
public class GetEmployees
{
    [Dependency("EmployeeService")]
    public IEmployeeService EmployeeService { get; set; 

    public IQueryable<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return EmployeeService.GetTable();
    }

    ...
}
```

In MVC I use a controller factory

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;

    public MyControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType != null)
        {
            return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
        }
    }
```

Global.asax

```
private static IUnityContainer InitContainer()
    {
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(unityContainer);

        return unityContainer;
    }
```

I pass the instance of UnityContainer into the Bootstrapper class.  The Bootstrapper class self registers all assemblies.

In the MVC Controllers, I inject the Business Logic like so:

```
public class EmployeeController
{
    [Dependency("GetEmployees")]
    public IBusinessLogic GetEmployees_Operations { get; set; }

    public ActionResult EmployeeMain()
    {   
        var employees = GetEmployees_Operations.GetAllEmployees();
        ...
    }
}
```

This all works great up to a point.  Every so often I will get an exception thrown from MyDataProvider class: "EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection".  This seems to happen during high use of the MVC site.  The exception is simple enough to understand, but how should I go about fixing it?

I found that changing how I instantiate the business logic class from a field on the controller to inside the ActionResult method, I don't recieve the exception.

For example:

```
public class EmployeeController
{
    //[Dependency("GetEmployees")]
    //public IBusinessLogic GetEmployees_Operations { get; set; }

    public ActionResult EmployeeMain()
    {   
        IBusinessLogic GetEmployees_Operations = _ioc_Bootstrapper.Resolve(typeof(IBusinessLogic), "GetEmployees") as IBusinessLogic;
        var employees = GetEmployees_Operations.GetAllEmployees();
        ...
    }
}
```

Have I completely missed the boat on this and implemented Unity incorrectly?

Bootstrapper code

```
private void RegisterDAL(String assembly)
    {
        var currentAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly);
        var assemblyTypes = currentAssembly.GetTypes();

        foreach (var assemblyType in assemblyTypes)
        {
            ...
            if (assemblyType.FullName.EndsWith("Provider"))
            {
                foreach (var requiredInterface in assemblyType.GetInterfaces())
                {
                    if (requiredInterface.FullName.EndsWith("DataProvider"))
                    {
                        var typeFrom = assemblyType.GetInterface(requiredInterface.Name);
                        var typeTo = assemblyType;
                        var injector = GetInjectorConstructor(assemblyType.Module.Name);
                        RegisterType(typeFrom, typeTo, false, injector);
                    }
                }

                continue;
            }

            ...
    }     

 private InjectionConstructor GetInjectorConstructor(String moduleName) 
 {
  ...
  connString = String.Concat("Data Source=MySqlServer, ";Initial Catalog=", catalogName, ";Application Name=", applicationName, ";Integrated Security=True; );
  var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
  return new InjectionConstructor(conn, true);
  }
```

Comment: Your description lacks (or I can't find it) the information on how the `SqlConnection` is registered.

Comment: It happens in the bootstrapper.  I added the code to the post.

Comment: Doesn't it inject the **very same** connection to each new instance of the provider?

Comment: Yes it does.  This is necessary for including multiple updates into a transaction.

Comment: Sql connections aren't supposed to be used concurrently. If you really share the same connection, it explains your issues under heavy load. Transactions under a single request should be handled on a single connection. Different requests should use different connection.

Comment: In one business logic class, I inject the EmployeeService and OfficeService.  Using different instances of the connection for each service would require escalation of the Transaction to MSDTC correct?

Comment: How would I assure then that the DataProvider injected into each service has it's own instance of the SQL Connection?

Comment: Use `InjectionFactory` instead of `InjectionConstructor`. The factory is actually a method that is invoked when a new instance is created. In the method you always create a new instance of the connection.

Comment: Outstanding.  I implemented this and was able to verify that each instance of the DataProvider did have a different instance of the SqlConnection.  The only concern I have is with perfomance.  Since I will no longer be sharing connections, all transactions will be escalated to MSDTC, even if the updates are for the same SQL Server database.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I would have another concern regarding the lifetime. You see, since you are on the asp.net stack, you should consider using PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager for the connection. This way you share the same connection in the same request which is ok. But, without a controller factory that also **disposes** objects at the end of the pipeline, you risk leaving connections undisposed.

Comment: That makes sense, but the framework is being consumed by non-ASP applications.  Would this have any effect on those, considering there would be no HttpContext?

Comment: The per request lifetime manager won't work in a nonasp environment. The transient (the one that always returns a new instance) is more appropriate there. And you still need to somehow dispose your data providers so that connections are also disposed.